# My stack is not displaying my array but queue display it

Tags: c++

My Queue is displaying right but my stack is displaying nothing. Im using array to transfer it to stack and to queue but when i transfer the array to stacks and display it, it show nothing. and is there a way to reverse my Queue and save it to my array again?

case 1 is where the input of stack and queue comes, void display in class stack is the problem I copied my whole stack on my stack project where I array transfer to stack but now when I transfer the array to stack and queue, stack gone missing.

```
class Stack { private:
    int MAX;
    int top;
    int *grd_s;

public:
    Stack (int size)
    {
        MAX=size;
        top=-1;
        grd_s=new int[MAX];
    }

    void push(int Q)
    {
    if ((top+1)==MAX)
        cout << "Stack Overflow..." << endl;
    top++;
    grd_s[top]=Q;
    }

    void display(int ctr)
    {
    cout<<"Cloud contains --"<<endl;
    for (int ctr=top; ctr>=0; ctr--)
    {
        if (ctr==top)
            cout<<"\t\t"<<grd_s[ctr]<<"<--Top of Stack"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"\t\t"<<grd_s[ctr]<<endl;
    }
    } };

class Queue { private:
    int front;
    int rear;
    int grd_q[5]; public:
    Queue()
    {
        front=-1;
        rear=-1;
        for (int z=0; z<5; z++)
        {
            grd_q[z]=0;
        }
    }
    bool isEmpty()
    {
        if (front==-1||rear==-1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    bool isFull()
    {
        if (rear==4)
            return  true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    void insert(int val)
    {
        if(isFull())
        {
            cout<<"Queue is Full..."<<endl;
            return;
        }
        else if (isEmpty())
        {
            rear=0;
            front=0;
            grd_q[rear]=val;
        }
        else
        {
            rear++;
            grd_q[rear]=val;
        }

    }
    void show()
    {
        cout<<"Local contains: "<<endl;
        for (int x=0; x<5; x++)
        {
            cout<<grd_q[x]<<" ";
        }
    }
    void rer()
    {
        cout<<"sad"<<endl;
    }

};

case 1:
    cout <<"Enter your 5 Grades" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            cout << "   " << i+1 << " . ";
            cin >> grd;
            Q[i] = grd;
        } system("cls"); break;
```

Comment: code makes no sense and won't compile. post something that will compile

Comment: my stack starts at -1 thats why I decrement it, that's right right?

Comment: Recommendation: Make a [mre]. Remove everything that's not necessary to demonstrate the problem. That means no menu, no user input, no `Queue, just ``Stack` and a simple `main` that loads up the stack and then fails to print it. Keep an eye on the compiler warnings, too. You might have one reporting that `Stack::display`'s `ctr` parameter is never used. It gets [shadowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) by `for (int ctr = top; ctr >= 0; ctr--)`

Comment: there is no error it launches the code but when I display the stack it will show stack contains -- just that.

Comment: user has input and transferred to stacks too so stacks should have elements using user's input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to construct your `Stack` outside the `do`-`while` loop.

As it stands right now, a new `Stack` is created at each iteration while the previous goes out of scope.
In doing so, you are creating your `Stack` in the input phase, only for it to get erased at end of the iteration!

Just modify the beginning of your `main()` function:

```
int main()
{
    Queue q1;
    Stack st(5);    // Put this line here, outside the loop!
    int Q[5];
    int choice;
    int chc;
    int chc2;
    int grd;

    system("cls");
 
do
{
    //  Stack st(5); Not here !
    displayRules();
    displayRules1();
    cin>>choice;
   ...
```

Comment: what? it fixes it, thank you but why it work outside do while but not inside?

Comment: As it stands right now, a new `Stack` is created at each iteration of the loop, while the previous `Stack`, instead, goes out of scope. So, the `Stack` you create in the input phase (phase 2, to cloud), that one only gets erased at end of the iteration, so when you are at phase 3, display, there is a new empty `Stack` that the program displays!

Comment: Variables that you define inside a scope (a scope is anything between two brackets {}, such as a loop iteration) disappear at the end of the scope. So if you want them to persist, you have to define them in an outer scope. Hopefully I managed to explain it clearly.

Comment: that explains why my queue got elements but stack doesn't have. thanks again